# Store and Retrieve JSON Data From Local Storage in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray

We get image for JSON url,And then We saved image in NSMutableArray(imageArray).
We have four different UIViewControls. Every Page uses this imageArray.
We are not interested to call web service every page.
We need imageArray Stored to Local JSON file and then we Retrieve Data form JSON.

So Please give me any idea.Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: do you  want image url or wants to  store images locally??

Comment: @hardikhadwani We get data(images or text or etc...) for JSON URL.And then Total data stored in One NSMutableArray.I need that NSMutableArray Stored in local save.json file.So it's easy to used ever page We think

Comment: In JSON Parsing you got image data or image url ?

Comment: @srinivasn i get images

Comment: then better to go with global Array which you can create in AppDelegate class.

Comment: Then you save images in cache folder, to cal the images form cache

Comment: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-tutorial-image-cache-and-loading-thumbnails-using-mknetworkkit/ http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-tutorial-image-cache-and-loading-thumbnails-using-mknetworkkit/ https://bpoplauschi.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/ios-image-caching-sdwebimage-vs-fastimage/

Comment: @PavanAlapati -- in which local DB u used in your project

Comment: @PavanAlapati my question is in  which local DB u used in your project

Answer (score 1):

Best solution to cache server response is to download the images using NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection, and use proper NSURLRequestCachePolicy to cache response.

To sort out your problem you can use `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad` cache policy. It will load data from server if there is no cache data locally and if found any local data then returns it without hitting server again.

For more on NSURLRequestCachePolicy and cache server response, you can read here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSURLRequestCachePolicy

http://www.hpique.com/2014/03/how-to-cache-server-responses-in-ios-apps/

http://codewithchris.com/preventing-nsurlconnection-cache-issues/

http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/